# Meteor JS: Inconsistency with Meteor JS when dealing with cursors?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I think I may have found some inconsistency within Meteor JS.
Firstly this is an example of a perfectly acceptable code that doesn't cause error within Meteor JS's Template Helper:

```
Template.admin_menu_items.helpers({
  menuItems: function(){
    console.log('inside menuItems');
    return MenuItems.find();
  },
})
```

However if I use Sessions to store the returned value of `MenuItems.find()`
e.g.

```
Template.admin_menu_items.rendered = function(){    
  var snapshot = MenuItems.find();
  Session.set('menu_items', snapshot);
}
```

Then use the object stored in the Sessions in the Template Helper:

```
Template.admin_menu_items.helpers({

      menuItems: function(){
        console.log('inside menuItems');

        //return MenuItems.find();
        return Session.get('menu_items');
      },
 })
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
meteor....ddc0aaf (line 888)
Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.
meteor....ddc0aaf (line 888)

badSequenceError@http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:179:1
ObserveSequence.observe/computation</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:144:1
Tracker.nonreactive@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:593:12
ObserveSequence.observe/computation<@http://localhost:3000/packages/observe-sequence.js?0532a9dd76dd78f543eb4d79a1e429df186d8bde:121:7
Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:327:5
Tracker.Computation.prototype._recompute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:346:9
Tracker._runFlush@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?6d0890939291d9780f7e2607ee3af3e7f98a3d9c:485:9
onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:372:11
```

Which DOES NOT MAKE SENSE because I am storing the acceptable return value of `MenuItems.find()` inside a Session and retrieving it....it should still be a cursor after retrieval.....right???

What's the explanation for this???

To emphasise that using Sessions to store the value does not change the object stored when retrieved....I tried the same code above but only with an array instead of a cursor...so that is `var snapshot = MenuItems.find().fetch();` instead of `var snapshot = MenuItems.find();` and with that it doesn't produce any errors.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the hood, `Session` is a [ReactiveDict](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/reactive-dict). If you have a look at the [source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js) you'll see it serializes its data via `EJSON.stringify`.

This works well if you have simple objects and primitives, however serializing a class instance will strip of all its methods (functions are not serialized).

This explains why storing the result of a `fetch` (an array of documents) works, whereas storing the result of a `find` (a cursor instance) doesn't. Because the cursor's methods were removed, it no longer behaves like a cursor, and spacebars will be unable to iterate over its documents.